# Domain Verification in PHP 5.6 issue with PHPMailer for sending mails via TLS

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, phpmailer, php-openssl

I am trying to send emails using PHPMailer with Let's Encrypt certificates but after shifting to PHP 5.6 it doesn't work due to failed Domain verification.

> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation >failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

The obvious workaround for this is to disable domain verification, but I am not willing to do the same as i want to know how this works

**The Output of the following**

```
php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());"

array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(36) "/usr/local/apps/etc/openssl/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(33) "/usr/local/apps/etc/openssl/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(35) "/usr/local/apps/etc/openssl/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(27) "/usr/local/apps/etc/openssl"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I have the cert.pem in the above mentioned location, but my certs and private keys are present in ***/etc/ssl***, i even tried to create a Sysmlink to those folder but still the verification fails.

So can anyone explain how the verification works as i am unable to figure out same even after days of googling the problem as most of the solution point to disabling domain verification.

I am i missing a something, as I have all the proper files related to the certificate and it's valid certificate as i am using it on my website.

**Here is the code for PHPMailer**

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 5;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'mydomin.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "test@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "test";
$mail->setFrom('test@mydomain.com', 'Hii');
$mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("<h2>Hello World</h2>");
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'verify_peer_name' => true,
    )
);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Quite right - you should definitely **not** disable verification, but you're getting things a little mixed up. If you're using your own *mail* server, then it should have access to and be configured to use the same certs as your web server - it's nothing to do with PHP config. I'd recommend setting `SMTPDebug = 3` - that's enough to debug this and is much less noisy than 4+, and you can also check that's it's configured correctly using openssl, as covered in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

Comment: I have configured **Exim** to use the Certificates, so can't seem to figure out why issue arises. I have also checked using command line and the out put shows a valid certificate

Comment: Check it with openssl. Most likely is either a name mismatch or unknown CA. I can't check it without knowing the domain.

Comment: I am using Let's Encrypt so i dont think there is any issue with the certs... the following command **openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:587** shows that i have a valid cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is not providing the letsencrypt X3 intermediate certificate in its response, only the leaf cert. This isn't enough because most CA stores don't contain the letsencrypt CA certs, only the root certs they are signed with, so you need the intermediate to bridge the two. Get the intermediate certificate from [here](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) and append it to your certificate file.

Here's how you can see it working from the client end:

```
$ wget https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt
$ openssl s_client -CAfile lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt -connect example.com:465
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

If you bundle that cert at the server end, it should work in all up to date clients without a local intermediate cert.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Synchro it worked......... days of frustration ended